# How to use analog mode GPIO pin(not ADC input channel) for ADC?

Tags: analog, adc, stm32, gpio

I want to use a GPIO pin which is configured to be "Analog Mode" for ADC.

I am working on STM32L073 series microcontroller. The pins with ADC input channels 
are used already. So I need to choose another pin to use ADC.

I could not find any information about how to use the analog mode gpio pin for ADC.

Is there anyway to configure a GPIO pin other than the pins with ADC input channels for ADC?

Comment: Is your board already made? You could use an external ADC or swap pins so you can use the normal channel. Possibly also a relay or other switch if you don't need both functions at the same time. I don't know anything about this processor though, so maybe there's a special way to use any GPIO pin for the ADC...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The pins with ADC input channels are used already.

The analog mode for a GPIO pad is just a multiplexer setting.   You still need the internal wiring to the ADC, which is only available for pins specified with an ADC channel marked ADC_INxx as additional function in table 16 of the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32l073rz.pdf).